# How to copy files to automatically created folders in the same shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, osx

I have created an Automator application that will create a new folder for a Project with subfolders with the help of a Shell Script. The application starts by asking for a Project Name and a Location (directory) and once it is created it opens the newly created project folder.

eg:

[image]

Up to that point it works as intended, however I am also trying to add some files to the subfolders automatically but I'm stuck and I haven't been able to find the solution on my own.

Basically I am trying to copy the files from another folder into one of the newly created subfolders but I'm getting (mostly) the following two errors:

1. The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory” usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
2. The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “cp: /path/to/sourcefile/file.pdf: No such file or directory”

   This is what I have:

[image]

```
mkdir "$1/$2"
mkdir "$1/$2/Guides_and_Bulletins"
mkdir "$1/$2/Pictures"
mkdir "$1/$2/Schematics"
mkdir "$1/$2/Schematics/Calculator"
mkdir "$1/$2/Schematics/As_built"
mkdir "$1/$2/Site_Docs"

cp "/path/to/sourcefile/file.pdf" "/$1/$2/Guides_and_Bulletins/file.pdf"
```

In that example I am trying to copy the file.pdf from one location to the newly created Guides_and_Bulletins subfolder from the actions above but of course it is not working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you

*Note: I of course am changing the path for cp **"/path/to/sourcefile/file.pdf"** "$1/$2/Guides_and_Bulletins/" to the correct one*

Comment: "All kinds of errors" is not a helpful piece of information.  I suspect you're getting multiple instances of **one** specific error, but you have not told us what that error is.  Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/550773/edit) to include the specific text of the error or errors you are encountering.

Comment: Yes. Sorry about the oversight. The two errors I get the most are the following: **The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory” usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory**

Comment: And also this one: **The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “cp: /path/to/sourcefile/file.pdf: No such file or directory”**

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/550773/edit) to include the errors.

Comment: @JimL. Done. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You created a directory:

```
mkdir "$1/$2"
```

But then you try to copy a file to a potentially different directory:

```
cp "/path/to/sourcefile/file.pdf" "/$1/$2/Guides_and_Bulletins/file.pdf"
```

Try:

```
cp "/path/to/sourcefile/file.pdf" "$1/$2/Guides_and_Bulletins/file.pdf"
```

Also, some simplification of your script is possible:

```
mkdir -p "$1/$2/Guides_and_Bulletins" \
         "$1/$2/Pictures" \
         "$1/$2/Schematics" \
         "$1/$2/Schematics/Calculator" \
         "$1/$2/Schematics/As_built" \
         "$1/$2/Site_Docs"

cp "/path/to/sourcefile/file.pdf" "$1/$2/Guides_and_Bulletins/"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion but I get: **The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “cp: /path/to/sourcefile/file.pdf: No such file or directory”**. Also, I used your simplification suggestion as well but now the name of the folder is just **mkdir $1** (I have it setup so that I can copy the project name from my schedule and the application gets the name automatically from the clipboard). EDIT: of course I'm changing the '/path/to/sourcefile/file.pdf' to the actual path name but it doesn't work

Comment: I am trying to make it work within Automator